# get scsi_device from scsi_generic

Tags: linux, udev

I'm enumerating scsi_generic devices with udev to retrieve the `/dev/sg*` filename so I can send an Inquiry to each device.

Can I also get the `/dev/sd*` filename (the scsi_device) while I'm right there?

If not, how do I get the scsi_device given a scsi_generic path?

This is my udev code:

```
IntPtr udev = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr enumerate = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{
    udev = Libudev.udev_new();
    if (udev == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new UdevException("Failed to create udev");

    enumerate = Libudev.udev_enumerate_new(udev);
    if (enumerate == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new UdevException("Failed to enumerate udev");

    Libudev.udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "scsi_generic");
    Libudev.udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);

    for (IntPtr listEntry = Libudev.udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);
         listEntry != IntPtr.Zero; 
         listEntry = Libudev.udev_list_entry_get_next(listEntry))
    {
        // Get the filename of the /sys entry for the device
        string deviceSysPath = Libudev.udev_list_entry_get_name(listEntry);

        IntPtr device = Libudev.udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, deviceSysPath);
        if (device == IntPtr.Zero)
            continue;

        // Get the /dev path of the device (/dev/sg*)
        string deviceDevPath = Libudev.udev_device_get_devnode(device);

        // Send Inquiry
        // <snip>

        Libudev.udev_device_unref(device);
    }
}
catch (DllNotFoundException ex)
{
    throw new DllNotFoundException("libudev is either not installed, or ldconfig has mapped it in an unexpected way. See source README file for information.", ex);
}
finally
{
    if (enumerate != IntPtr.Zero)
        Libudev.udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    if (udev != IntPtr.Zero)
        Libudev.udev_unref(udev);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by performing two enumerations. First by enumerating over `scsi_generic` devices, then by `block` devices.

I create a hash table (`Dictionary< string, string >`) to map the generic device's sysname to its devnode.

While enumerating `scsi_generic` devices I get the parent (`udev_device_get_parent`), then get the sysname (`udev_device_get_sysname`) and add it to the map. For SCSI disks, you get something like "9:0:0:0".

While enumerating `block` devices I do the same: Get the parent and the sysname. If the hash table contains the same key, I have found the generic device that matches the block device.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the device serial number with the INQUIRY command and then use the serial number to find the associated block device in `/dev/disk/by-id/`:

```
$ sudo sg_inq --page=sn /dev/sg0
VPD INQUIRY: Unit serial number page
  Unit serial number: 110427E3834563H46N0N
$ basename $(readlink /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_*110427E3834563H46N0N)
sda
```

Comment: That seems rather round-about, and it defeats the purpose of using udev which (as I understand it) is to not make any assumptions about the structure of /dev.

Comment: OK. Then I suggest that you iterate over block devices (sda, sdb) rather than on SCSI generic devices and retrieve the SCSI properties filled by udev. For instance: `for dev in $(ls /dev/sd?); do udevadm info -q all -n $dev | grep SCSI; done`

Comment: I think you're right that I need to enumerate disks and find the generic from that. I can see that a direct path exists in sysfs between the two (from disk to generic), the question then becomes: How do I do it strictly with udev?

Comment: Match the "block" subsystem instead of the "scsi_generic" subsystem: `Libudev.udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "block")`